# Angular2 and jQuery Ajax POST call transofrmRequest

Tags: jquery, ajax, angular

I'am trying to change my application from angularJS to angular2 and I've stuck with ajax POST call.

```
return $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.url.com",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        method: 'POST',
        transformRequest: function (obj) {
            var str = [];
            for (var p in obj)
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
        },
        data: user
    });
```

in angular2 I can't use transformRequest function, so the question is how to change this code fragment:

```
    transformRequest: function (obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    }
```

to make it work in angular2?

Comment: Can you explain what the `transformRequest` function does and what `obj` contains?

Comment: [Why would you not just use the Angular 2 HTTP Client?](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `transformRequest` in jQuery ajax  is used to transform the request parameters to a particular object.

In Angular2 there is no function to alter the request inside the http service call. Instead what I suggest you to do is to create the request in an outside function and use that object in the http call.

```js
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
headers.append('Accept', "*/*");

let options = new RequestOptions();
options.headers = headers;
http.post('http://www.url.com', requestObject,options).subscribe(...);
```

Here the `requestObject` is a *transformed* object.